# Update an XML file using data read from a CSV file

Tags: xml, perl, csv, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to write a value to an XML file. I have a CSV input file `Input.xsv` and an XML template file `template.xml` which I need to update with the Name and IP Address values from the CSV file.

#### Input.csv (Name, IP Address)

```
LAB-1,10.26.0.1
LAB-2,10.26.0.2
LAB-3,10.26.0.3
```

#### template.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:networkdevice
        xmlns:ns0="network.ers.ise.cisco.com" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns1="ers.ise.cisco.com"
        xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com"
        name="name1">
    <authenticationSettings>
        <enableKeyWrap>true</enableKeyWrap>
        <keyEncryptionKey>1234567890123456</keyEncryptionKey>
        <keyInputFormat>ASCII</keyInputFormat>
        <networkProtocol>RADIUS</networkProtocol>
        <radiusSharedSecret>aaa</radiusSharedSecret>
    </authenticationSettings>
    <coaPort>1700</coaPort>
    <NetworkDeviceIPList>
        <NetworkDeviceIP>
            <ipaddress>1.1.1.1</ipaddress>
            <mask>32</mask>
        </NetworkDeviceIP>
    </NetworkDeviceIPList>
</ns0:networkdevice>
```

I want to read names and IP addresses from the CSV file and to write them into my XML template file to create an HTTP POST request for each device in the CSV file.

I tried to save the values in my XML template, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;
use XML::TreeBuilder;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xmlbase    = 'template.xml';
my $paramsfile = 'input.csv';

# The list of tags filled from the CSV file
my @taglist = qw( name ipaddress );

my $tree = XML::TreeBuilder->new();
$tree->parsefile($xmlbase);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $paramsfile or die "$paramsfile: $!";

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {

    my $contree = XML::TreeBuilder->new();
    $contree->parsefile($xmlbase);

    my $index = 0;

    for my $tagname ( @taglist ) {        
        my $tag = $contree->look_down('_tag' => $tagname);
        $tag->push_content($row->[$index++]);
    }
}

print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
print $tree->as_XML();
```

After I run my script I get this error:

> Can't locate object method "push_content"in this line

This error refers to the statement `$tag->push_content($row->[$index++]);`. I think it is because `name` does not have its own tag.

This element I have here:

```
<ns0:networkdevice
        xmlns:ns0="network.ers.ise.cisco.com"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns1="ers.ise.cisco.com"
        xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com"
        name="name1">
```

in tag `ns0:networkdevice`

When I try with just `ipaddress` it is printed, but with the original value from `template.xml`. It does not take a value from `Input.csv`, and if it was empty, it stays empty.

How should I do this?

Comment: Your program logic is wrong: You are creating object `$tree` outside the loop. Then you are creating, modifying and without doing anything useful discarding `$contree`. Finally you are printing the original unmodified `$tree` object as XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with `XML::Treebuilder` so will give an example in `XML::Twig`. I will also avoid `Text::CSV` because I think it's overkill for most CSV use cases (e.g. any time you're not worrying about quoting/multi-line).

But it would go something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'template.xml' );
$xml ->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

open ( my $input, '<', 'input.csv' ) or die $!;

while ( <$input> ) {
   chomp;
   my ( $name, $ip ) = split /,/;
   $xml -> root -> set_att('name', $name );
   $xml -> get_xpath('//ipaddress',0) -> set_text($ip);

   $xml -> print;
}
```

For the last line of your CSV, this will generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:networkdevice
    name="LAB-3"
    xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com"
    xmlns:ns0="network.ers.ise.cisco.com"
    xmlns:ns1="ers.ise.cisco.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <authenticationSettings>
    <enableKeyWrap>true</enableKeyWrap>
    <keyEncryptionKey>1234567890123456</keyEncryptionKey>
    <keyInputFormat>ASCII</keyInputFormat>
    <networkProtocol>RADIUS</networkProtocol>
    <radiusSharedSecret>aaa</radiusSharedSecret>
  </authenticationSettings>
  <coaPort>1700</coaPort>
  <NetworkDeviceIPList>
    <NetworkDeviceIP>
      <ipaddress>10.26.0.3</ipaddress>
      <mask>32</mask>
    </NetworkDeviceIP>
  </NetworkDeviceIPList>
</ns0:networkdevice>
```

Which looks like what you're after?

You'd be wanting `$xml -> sprint` if you're wanting to include it in a `POST` or similar though.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to generate XML from Perl is to use [XML::FromPerl](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::FromPerl).

The template is replaced by a Perl data structure embedded in your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::FromPerl qw(xml_from_perl);

my $name = 'LAB-1';
my $ip   = '10.26.0.1';

my $xml = xml_from_perl
  [ 'ns0:networkdevice' => { 'xmlns:ns0' => 'network.ers.ise.cisco.com',
                 'xmlns:xs'  => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
                 'xmlns:ns1' => 'ers.ise.cisco.com',
                 'xmlns:ers' => 'ers.ise.cisco.com',
                 name => $name },
    [ authenticationSettings =>
      [ enableKeyWrap => 'true' ],
      [ keyEncryptionKey => '1234567890123456' ],
      [ keyInputFormat => 'ASCII' ],
      [ networkProtocol => 'RADIUS' ],
      [ radiusSharedSecret => 'aaa' ] ],
    [ coaPort => '1700' ],
    [ NetworkDeviceIPList =>
      [ NetworkDeviceIP =>
    [ ipaddress => $ip ],
    [ mask => 32 ] ] ] ];

say $xml->toString(1);
```

Comment: Cool! Thank's, But how I read values from csv in your example?

Comment: Using `Text::CSV` as you are already doing. You see `$name` and `$ip` are inserted into the XML, right? You only have to set their values to be equal to those read from the CSV file.